# How would you process an image puzzle webapp on either the server side or the client side?

Tags: vue.js, erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, image-manipulation

I am building a web app game which simply takes an image file as an input from the filesystem, divides the image into blocks, then puts the image blocks randomly so that the client-side user can relocate the blocks to restore the original image.

The platform I will be using is Elixir/Phoenix language/framework on the backend and VueJS on the front end. When I tried to manipulate image with Erlang, I had some difficulty to find libraries for pixel manipulation. But then I thought, if every user's puzzle image will have to be created on the server, it will cost a lot of resources anyway.

Do you think it's better to send the image from the server's filesystem to a client-side and create the image blocks on the client-side with Javascript or you would do it with Erlang/Elixir on the server side?

What would be your preferred method on a scientific basis, pros and cons?

Comment: I would do it on client side via canvas api and wrapper frameworks. However, you can move part of the algorithm to the serverside if you want to hide it from the client (to make cheating harder etc.) Phoenix's Channels are there to help you! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i am doing it.

```
# Args Explantion :
    # -resize 72x72! - Resizes the passed Image, `!` means don't care about aspect ratio
    # -crop 24x24 - Crops the image
    # -scene 1 - Start naming the cropped images starting with index 1
    # -%02d - produces output such as 00, 01, 02, 03
    # image_size - Actual image size
    # seg_size - Size of small segments/cropped images
    list = [
      "#{img_path}",
      "-resize",
      "#{image_size} x #{image_size}!",
      "-crop",
      "#{seg_size} x #{seg_size}",
      "-scene",
      "1",
      "#{new_tmp}/%02d.png"
    ]

    System.cmd("convert", list)
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with [`ImageMagick`](https://www.imagemagick.org) command line wrapper.

As by [cropping documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile), somewhat like below would do:

> ```
> convert my_image: -repage 60x40-5-3 \
>  -crop 30x20 +repage my_image_tiles_%d.png`
> ```

Although there is an Elixir wrapper for `IM`, called [`Mogrify`](https://hexdocs.pm/mogrify), it implements a limited set of operations, so I usually go with [`System.cmd/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#cmd/3).

For each input file you might create tiles and next time the file is being accessed, you might start with a check. If the file was already cropped, just serve the tiles, otherwise crop it before serving tiles. This would be basically a clean server-side one-liner, prone to reverse engineering, unlike client-side solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your geometry parameter you specific -5-3 I get it from the manuals that this is an offset, but I still do not know why you specified -5-3 how different it would be if we removed them. I will try it anyway, but I thought of hearing your opinion.

Comment: I just copy-pasted the example. You are obviously to calculate the numbers yourself, depending on the number of tiles to produce.